# Matplotlib axis tick format changes after zoom in ipython figure window

Tags: python, matplotlib

In ipython figure windows, I have observed the following feature that I would like to turn off:

Here's a plot I made using the pyplot.errorbar() inside of an ipython terminal. In this figure, the horizontal axis tick label format is behaving the way I would like it to:

[image]

However, upon zooming in to get a closer look at what is going on with the clustered points around x=2000 using the pan/zoom feature (the compass icon in the figure above), the tick label format changes to one that is harder to read quickly, inappropriate for presentations, and changes as you continue to zoom! i.e. the number whose placeholder is "+1.999e3" changes with zoom.

[image]

I would much prefer the tick labels on the horizontal axis to show 2000, 2000.5, 2001, 2001.5, etc.

I see the following preamble after typing ipython --pylab in my terminal:

Python 2.7.5 (default, Dec  2 2013, 16:07:04) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined in [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#default-formatter) you can use

```
ax = pyplot.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```